# Beamer: Multiple videos simultaneously with autoplay?

Tags: beamer, media9

I am trying to make presentation in Beamer and add 2 vides on one slide. Here comes the problem: I want to start them immediately after opening the slide using autoPlay=true, but only one video starts and the rest of them need to be to started with mouse click.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{frame}   
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5.5cm}
        \begin{figure}                  
            \centering  
            \includemedia[label=vidA,
                          addresource=Video1/pohyb1.mp4,
                          activate=pageopen,width=4cm,height=3cm,
                          flashvars={
                          source=Video/pohyb1.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=true
                          }]{}{VPlayer.swf}
        \end{figure}            
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{5.5cm}
        \begin{figure}                  
            \centering  
            \includemedia[label=video2,
                         addresource=Video/pohyb2.mp4,
                         activate=pageopen,width=4cm, height=3cm,
                         flashvars={
                         source=Video/pohyb2.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=true
                         }]{}{VPlayer.swf}
        \end{figure}                                                    
    \end{column}
\end{columns}   
\end{frame}
```

Do someone know, why it doesn't work and how to fix it? Is it possible to do it witout using buttons?

Tomas

Comment: Well, actually it is not a duplicate, but a real bug in `VPlayer.swf`. It should indeed be possible to start multiple videos at once and automatically when the page opens.  On CTAN, there is an update of `media9` [0.54 2015-06-23] available with a recompiled `VPlayer.swf` that fixes the reported problem.